# how to define a typescript module in a separate project

Tags: typescript

I have a project that has the following structure:

```
- ProjectA
  | - file.ts
  | - tsconfig.json
- ProjectB
  | - file.ts
  | - tsconfig.json
- ProjectC
  | icons/
  | | - icon.svg
```

I have babel and webpack setup and working to convert the `icon.svg` into a react component when imported in `file.ts` in either project A or B so that is working without issue. The thing I'm running into is how to define what `*.svg` is in both A and B.

I'm able to add a `declarations.d.ts` file to the root of A and B that contains

```
export type IconComponentType = React.FunctionComponent<{
  size: number
  color: string
}>

declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: IconComponentType
  export default content
}
```

and things work as expected, but I'd rather not repeat this file. The problem is no matter what I do I don't seem to be able to add the above to `Project C` or even the root of my project and have `Project A` and `Project B` pick it up.

the `tsconfig.json` of A an B look like:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "projectC": ["../projectC"]
    }
  }
}
```